# QT / CE on Windows CE 6.0, app won't run

Tags: qt, qt4, windows-ce

I'm a .NET CF developer trying to move to QT/CE. I'm trying to port one of my app written in .NET CF to QT/CE targeted run on Windows Embedded CE 6.0 GPS made by China. I don't have access to original SDK (china manufacturers don't provide them) so, as QT mailing lists suggested, I used Windows CE 5.0 Standard SDK as my option.
Here is my config

configure -platform win32-msvc2008 -xplatform wince50standard-armv4i-msvc2008 -release -static -fast -nomake docs -nomake demos -nomake examples

The QT compilation process goes well, I created new project in VS2008 and tried to run it on the device but I faced an error in VS "Error Unable to Start Program.  Cannot find..."
I go to device's Program Files and I can see the project folder and inside it, I can see, project.exe and msvcr90.dll. However, when I double-click project.exe nothing happens. I right clicked the project.exe and select open, nothing happens.

Could anyone help me what's going on with my problems?

Comment: In your target device, try copying the msvcr90.dll to "\windows".  That seems to work for me.  I am guessing that applications in Windows CE will look at the \Windows folder for DLLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you have msvcrt90.dll in there is a big red flag.  That's the desktop C runtimes, which indicates to me that you're probably building against some desktop SDK or that somehow the desktop runtimes and dependencies are getting sucked in.

Did you run depends.exe against the output binary to see what's actually coming out the end of the sausage factory?